# redirect using document ready does not work

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

here below is my code i can't seem to find what is wrong it is not redirecting to the link.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= baseurl(); ?>/public/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript">            
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(function() { $("formRedirect").submit(); });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id='formRedirect' action="http://www.example.com/something/something.aspx" method="post"><input type="submit" name="redirect" value='<?= $token ?>'</form> 
</body>
```

Comment: You forgot the `#` in `$("#formRedirect")`.

Comment: Why `$(function()` inside `$(document).ready(function()`?

Comment: in order to redirect to another page use window.location.href='your url goes here';

Answer (score 1):

For id jquery detect them with `#`

Try like this

```
$("#formRedirect")[0].submit();
```

Use

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

or

```
$(function(){})
```

Both same

Comment: $( "#formRedirect" ).submit(); it triggers the external submit handler which prevents the default action

Comment: should my code redirect me to the other website i am accessing?.. i am only getting a blank page as of now

Comment: nope you should use ajax to handle submit things. now you are redirecting to `action="http://www.example.com/something/something.aspx"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= baseurl(); ?>/public/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">            
        $(document).ready(function() { 
         $("#formRedirect").submit(); 
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id='formRedirect' action="http://www.example.com/something/something.aspx" method="post"><input type="submit" name="redirect" value='<?= $token ?>'</form> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

U have added `$(function(){});` inside `document.ready`

`$(function(){});` is similar to `$(document).ready(function() {});`

Use following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $("#formRedirect").submit(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the Chrome console to be very helpful in debugging situations like this. I would start by making sure you are getting a result from your jQuery selector.

You can open the Chrome console by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>

In the Chrome console, type `$("formRedirect")` and see if you get any results. You probably won't, since you are missing the `#` ID selector.

Next, try submitting your corrected jQuery object. If it doesn't work, try accessing the actual HTML object by adding in a `[0]` at the end of your selector, as suggested by @Anik.